# facing problem with date picker in android

Tags: android

in my application i have to date picker as From date and To date. I am using onCreateDialog() method. So first time i am selecting the dates from date picker and putting them in the edit text. then when again i am selecting the date from the date picker, in the date picker it is showing the date which i already selected. But if i move to other search in the same screen(Activity) and try to pick the date from date picker, date picker still is showing the previous date. not the current date.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID1:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener,  c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                c.get(Calendar.MONTH),  c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


    case DATE_DIALOG_ID2:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener2,  c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                c.get(Calendar.MONTH),  c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try writing your question clearly once again, but to my understanding of your question you might want to look at your onDateChanged() callback method. I assume you have a updateDialog() method inside this onDateChanged(), you might want to check that method for err's.

I suppose you looked this link where they showed how to use a date picker http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html

good luck

For the 2nd question you asked about mixup in from and to date dialog

From what you are saying, I think there something like a small error like

1) R.id.datepicker2 being used in place of R.id.datepicker1

or

2) having mixs up in onDateChangedListener(). I am sure there is better way to do it, but try checking whether you have like this below 2 different listeners

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);    



DatePicker fromDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    datePicker.init(mYear, mMonth, mDay, new OnDateChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            //things you want to happen when datepicker1 is changed in your case the From date field     


        }
    });

DatePicker toDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    datePicker.init(mYear, mMonth, mDay, new OnDateChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            //things you want to happen when datepicker2 is changed in your case the To date field     


        }
    });
```

Comment: I fix the above problem partially..But now i am facing a problem. I have two date field. One is 'From Date' and another is 'To Date'. Now first time, if i click on From and To date, both are giving Todays Date only. Now suppose i select From Date as 26/01/2011 and To date 15/02/2011. Then again if i click the From Date field, Datepicker is showing 15/02/2011. can anyone help me.

Comment: @Arindam you might want to check the edits made to the above answer and see if it fixes your issue

Comment: Its fixed. in on Prepare Dialog switch case, i forgot to give break in every case.

Comment: I don't think the problem was due to absence break keyword. You have used used return keyword and that is OK.